# Segmentation fault при обращении к указателю

Tags: linux, c, указатели, malloc, memory-management

Решил для развития кругозора написать собственную имплементацию аллокатора памяти под *Linux*, но при написании столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

Вызов `sbrk()` возвращает указатель на начало выделенной памяти, затем я этот указатель привожу к указателю на структуру `Hdr`. Но когда я пытаюсь задать значение переменной по этому указателю, программа вылетает с *Segmentation error*. Чутьё подсказывает, что я делаю глупость, ведь структуру нужно инициализировать прежде чем использовать, но я не знаю как в данной ситуации правильно это сделать, учитывая, что память под структуру уже выделена вызовом `sbrk()`.

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь!

```
struct Hdr {
  int is_avaible;
  int size;
};

void *malloc(long memory_size) {
  void *memory_location;
  struct Hdr *current_location_struct;
  ...
  memory_location = sbrk(memory_size);
  if (memory_location == NULL)
    return;
  current_location_struct = (struct Hdr *)memory_location;
  current_location_struct->is_available = 0;
  ...
}
```

Comment: @user1496491  Вам следует проверять, был ли вызов функции успешным. А также является ли адрес соответствующим образов выравнен.

Comment: Я просто приведу цитату из умной книжки (речь о паре `brk()/sbrk()`): *"Еще более практично вообще никогда не использовать эти процедуры. Программа, которая их использует, не может затем использовать также и malloc(), и это создает большую проблему, поскольку многие элементы стандартной библиотеки полагаются на использование malloc(). Поэтому использование brk() или sbrk() может приводить к трудно обнаруживаемым крушениям программы."*

Comment: Скорее всего segfault Вы получаете где-то в другом месте, еще до описываемых действий, например, при попытке печати, когда fopen (неявно вызываемый при инициализации программы) обращаетеся к вашей malloc

Comment: @avp SegFault точно возникает на описанной строке - проверено флагами.

Comment: Не понял. Вообще-то такие программы (когда меняете стандартный аллокатор) реально можно отлаживать только под отладчиком. А так, маловато информации, чтобы что-то советовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим как работает `sbrk()`. Схематично:

```
void *sbrk(intptr_t increment) 
{
    void *heap_ptr = current_heap_end;

    if( increment > 0 ) {
        if( !expand_process_heap( increment ) ) {
            heap_ptr = (void *)-1;
        }
    }
    else if( increment < 0 ) {
        heap_ptr = reduce_process_heap( -increment );
    }
    return heap_ptr;
}
```

Рассмотрим с конца.

1. Если `increment` равен `0`, то возвращаем текущий адрес конца кучи.
2. Если отрицателен, то уменьшаем кучу и возвращаем адрес нового её конца.
3. И если он положителен, то увеличиваем кучу и возвращаем старое его значение.

Вот как раз пункт 3 ошибочно многими (не только начинающими программистами, но и книгописателями!) воспринимается как некий способ выделить память. Формально - да, как бы "память выделяется", как раз размером `increment` байтов. Но на деле эту память использовать по своему усмотрению *напрямую* нельзя! Потому что пытаясь туда что-то записать вы "сбиваете настройки" системному менеджеру памяти, что закономерно приводит к краху программы. Конечно, в случае реальной программы, а не в учебных примерах, в которых после использования `sbrk()` и вывода каких-то демо-значений в программе больше ничего не происходит.

P.S. Кстати, если бы вы перед чтением сомнительной :) литературы прочитали [man sbrk](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sbrk&category=2&russian=2), то обратили бы внимание на следующее:

> On success, `sbrk()` returns the previous program break. (If the break was increased, then this value is a pointer to the start of the newly allocated memory). **On error, (void *) -1 is returned**, and errno is set to ENOMEM.

P.P.S. Я уж не говорю о том, что заменить библиотечный `malloc()` своей реализацией - это не просто выстрелить себе в ногу, это усесться на связку гранат, облиться бензином и подорвать их.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, пойду переделывать на mmap'ах. Ну а заменяю библиотечную malloc() я в виртуалке, так что никаких серьёзных последствий быть не может.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛатышев, скорее всего вы просто не сможете запустить программу сложней `return 0;`. Посмотрите хотя бы для начала как реальный `malloc()` выглядит внутри, и сколько всего он за собой тащит.

Comment: Ну, все не так грустно, простенький вариант с sbrk из сотни строчек вроде бы работает.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то меня зацепило всеобщее недоверие к реализации своего malloc через sbrk.

Вот очень простая (по сути дурацкая), но работающая программка, просто для демонстрации возможности работы с `sbrk()`.

Поскольку вся группа функций (malloc/calloc/realloc/free) используется библиотечным софтом совместно, то реализовывать один лишь `malloc` нельзя.

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


static void *start;
void *
get_memstart ()
{
  return start;
}

// size multiples 16, allocated to bound multiples 16
struct bhdr {
  struct hdr {
    size_t bsize;
    uint cnt;
    char is_free;
  } hdr;
  char pad[(16 - sizeof(struct hdr)) & 15];
};


// each malloc returns new sbrk block
void *
malloc (size_t size)
{
  static uint cnt = 0;
  const char *mtxt = "mmalloc\n";
  if (write(1, mtxt, strlen(mtxt)))
    cnt++;

  if (!size)
    return 0;

  // increase space to mutilpe 16 for good bounding
  struct bhdr *p = (typeof(p))sbrk((15 + size + sizeof(*p)) & ~15);

  if ((long)p == -1L)
    return 0;
  if (!start)
    start = p;
  p->hdr.bsize = size;
  p->hdr.cnt = cnt;
  p->hdr.is_free = 0;

  return p + 1;
}

void *
calloc (size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
  const char *mtxt = "mcalloc\n";
  void *p = 0;

  if (write(1, mtxt, strlen(mtxt))) {
    p = malloc(nmemb * size);
    if (p)
      memset(p, 0, nmemb * size);
  }
  return p;
}

// mark early allocated block as free if bound is multiple 16
void
free (void *ptr)
{
  const char *mtxt = "mfree\n";
  if (write(1, mtxt, strlen(mtxt)))
    if (!ptr || (long)ptr & 15)
      return;

  struct bhdr *p = (typeof(p))ptr;
  p[-1].hdr.is_free = 1;
}

// if new size greater than old size returns copy in new block
void *
realloc (void *ptr, size_t size)
{
  const char *mtxt = "mrealloc\n";
  if (write(1, mtxt, strlen(mtxt)))
    if (!ptr)
      return malloc(size);
  if ((long)ptr & 15)
    return 0;
  if (!size) {
    free(ptr);
    return (void *)-1L;
  }

  struct bhdr *p = (typeof(p))ptr;
  size_t tsz = p[-1].hdr.bsize;
  if (tsz >= size)
    return ptr;

  void  *nptr = malloc(size);
  if (nptr)
    memcpy(nptr, ptr, tsz);

  return nptr;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct bhdr b;
  printf("Hello, sbrk/malloc!\nbhdr: %d  pad: %d  hdr: %d\n",
         (int)sizeof(b),
         (int)sizeof(b.pad),
         (int)sizeof(b.hdr));

  char *s = 0;
  size_t n;

  errno = 0;
  while ((fputs("Enter: ", stdout), getline(&s, &n, stdin)) > 0) {
    printf("read %s", s);
    if (*s == '.') {
      puts("New line mem");
      free(s);
      s = 0;
    }
  }
  perror("stdin");

  return fcloseall();
}
```

Все "странности" кода с `write()` связаны с раздражающими (идиотскими) warnings gcc/g++ (g++.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0) вызываемым с ключами оптимизации (`-O...`) когда результат write не используется.

Comment: А чем вызваны явные приведения типа вида `(typeof(p))` в ситуациях, когда правая часть имеет тип `void *`? Популярный в определенных кругах аргумент вроде "а так я сразу вижу конкретный тип" тут не работает, ибо от `(typeof(p))` конкретный тип виднее не становится :) Так зачем они тут? Разве что желание компилироваться и под gnuС++..

Comment: @AnT, вот именно -- кресты проклятые -) (оттуда же и `#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE`) . Никогда не помню тэги в вопросе и поэтому компилю обоими.